# Android, Xamarin and Prism how to use physical keyboard with buttons?

Tags: android, xamarin, keyboard, prism

I've got device with physical keyboard (terminal device with scanner). I want to use Enter button on this keyboard to let's say close dialog with one button (do the same event as button clicked). How to do this?

```
            <Button     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        x:Name="ButtonOk"
                        Text="Ok"
                        Command="{Binding DoConfirmBtn}">
                <Button.Behaviors>
                    <prism:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="?"   <-- what should I put here to check enter pressed?
                            Command="{Binding DoConfirmBtn}" />
                </Button.Behaviors>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Do you use `Xamarin.Forms` or `Xamarin` (native)? To access the keyboard, you have to use platform-specific code (because there's no `InputBindings` in forms).

Comment: I'm using  Xamarin.Forms with Prism